# jQuery is loading 2x in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

On our Wordpress installation it seems as though jQuery is loading twice. Removing either seems so break the site and we can't figure out what to do. Any thoughts?

2 files are being loaded:

1. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
2. https://www.example.com/…-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4

In theme functions:

```js
add_filter( 'wp_default_scripts', 'remove_jquery_migrate' );

function remove_jquery_migrate( &$scripts)
{
    if(!is_admin())
    {
        $scripts->remove( 'jquery');
        $scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core' ), '1.2.1' );
    }
}
```

In theme header:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perhaps your theme is using deprecated code from the 1.2.1 version? It's very likely there's been some fundamental (breaking) changes since then (jquery is at v3 right now). Not a big deal (they should be able to coexist due to jquery's Noconflict mode), just make sure you're getting a minified version of both.